# existence of an Id in multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 10 dataframes with similar columns, and I want to check if there is any id that exist in at least 8 of those dataframes. How should I do that

Comment: You could `concat` with keys, then groupby

Answer (score 0):

```py
import collections
li=[]
for df in [df1,df2,df3]:  # List your dataframe names here
  li+=df.columns.values.tolist()
counter = collections.Counter(li)

# counter is a dictionary with key value pairs of each column name with its frequency count

print(list(k for k,v in counter.items() if v>=8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty example to explain how you could do it:

Rename the columns where the id is, so they all have the same name, then do something like this

```py
for df in list_of_dfs:
    if specific_value in df.columnname.values:
        counter+= 1
        if counter >= 8:
            print(specific_value,' is in ',counter,' Dataframes')
```

Just remember, with this you can test if something is in your df or not. (Returns True/False)

```py
specific_value in df.columnname.values
```